# How to toast a message said that the "email message has been sent successfully"?

Tags: java, android, email, android-intent, sendmail

Can someone help me, how to figure out, how to toast a message said that the "email message has been sent successfully" or "email failed to send"?

```
Intent sendEmail = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND);

sendEmail.setType("plain/text");
sendEmail.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_EMAIL, new String[]{"fypadawiyahjalil@gmail.com"});
sendEmail.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_SUBJECT, subject);
sendEmail.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT,
        "Name: "+name+'\n'+"Email: "+email+'\n'+"Message: "+'\n'+message);

startActivity(Intent.createChooser(sendEmail, "Send mail..."));

@Override
public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data)
{
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);

    if(requestCode==1)
    {
        if(requestCode == 1 && resultCode == Activity.RESULT_OK)
        {
            Toast.makeText(ContactUs.this, "Your message has been sent successfully.", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            loadingBar.dismiss();
        }
        else if (requestCode == 1 && resultCode == Activity.RESULT_CANCELED)
        {
            Toast.makeText(ContactUs.this, "Mail cancelled.", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            loadingBar.dismiss();
        }
        else
        {
            Toast.makeText(ContactUs.this, "Please try again.", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            loadingBar.dismiss();
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It's not currently possible to do that because it is not part of the API.

The code you have will only return the "Mail cancelled" toast message every time.

`Intent.ACTION_SEND` will always return the default value of `RESULT_CANCELED` since it does not have any output.

Also, the API does not know whether an email is sent or not, hence it will never return `RESULT_OK`.

Comment: then should I continue to toast the message?

Comment: Unfortunately no, currently there is no workaround this.